# How to adjust a PMF such that Expected Value remains identical?

Tags: probability, statistics, systems-of-equations, expected-value

I have the following PMF, for a random variable $X_i, i \in \{0, 1, 2 , 3\}$

$$
P(x_0) = 0.5 \\
P(x_1) = 0.2 \\
P(x_2) = 0.2 \\
P(x_3) = 0.1 \\
$$

The expected value, $E(X)$, is $$E(X) = 0 * 0.5 + 1 * 0.2 + 2 * 0.2 + 3 * 0.1 = 0.9$$

Now, I want to adjust this PMF slightly, such that $P(x_2) = 0.29$, but conditioned on the fact that I want the expected value, $E(X)$ to remain at $0.9$.

How do I remove the added probability, $0.09$, from the other possibilities($0, 1, 3$), such that $E(X) = 0.9$

My thoughts/attempts:

If I naively try and remove the added probability equally from the remaining possibilities, then I would be removing $0.09/3 = 0.03$ from each of them, resulting in a new PMF:

$$
P(x_0) = 0.47 \\
P(x_1) = 0.17 \\
P(x_2) = 0.29 \\
P(x_3) = 0.07 \\
$$

which gives me an expected value of $$E(X) = 0 * 0.47 + 0.17 + 2 * 0.29 + 3 * 0.07 = 0.96$$

which is different to the previous expected value.

Let $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \geq 0$ the the probabilities we need to remove from $\{0, 1, 3\}$ respectively.

Then, we want
$$
\alpha + \beta + \gamma = 0.09, \\ 
0 * (0.5 - \alpha) + 1 * (0.2 - \beta) + 2 * 0.29 + 3 * (0.1 - \gamma) = 0.9
$$

Now, the last equation rearranges to $$\beta + 3\gamma = 0.18 $$

I have $2$ equations here and need to find $3$ variables, so I'm not sure this is possible?

Is there a way I can potentially brute force this / estimate it? As in, try and get as close to $0.9$ as possible?

Comment: "I have 2 equations here and need to find 3 variables, so I'm not sure this is possible?"
On the contrary, that says that (in general, and here in particular) you have many (infinite) solutions.

Comment: You could just add the $0.09$ to $P(x_2)$; then since $1$ is half of $2$, reduce $P(x_1)$ by twice as much, i.e. $0.18$. $P(x_0)$ can be whatever it needs to be to make the probabilities sum to 1, since it does not affect the expected value. Then $E[X] = 0.59(0) + 0.02(1) + 0.29(2) + 0.1(3) = 0.9$ still. Of course, this is just an arbitrary one of many possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Take $\alpha =0$. You will get unique values for $\beta$ and $\gamma$ from your equations.  [$\beta=\gamma =0.045]$.

Comment: Is there a way to do this where $\alpha > 0$?

Comment: Why? There is no reason to change all the probabilities other than $P(x_2)$.  Yes, you can make $\alpha >0$ also,  but you achieve nothing by doing that.  @theman

Comment: Just from a probabilistic point of view, if I increase $P(x_2)$, then I would at least expect $P(x_0)$ to decrease slightly. How is it possible to solve this with $\alpha > 0$?

Comment: You are just wasting your time. You don't have to decrease all three probabilities. It is illogical to me.

Comment: @theman It should be obvious from my answer that if you choose $\alpha$ to be  a very small positive number you can solve for $\beta$ and $\gamma$. This  site is meant to assist you in discovering proofs  and you are refusing to to do some work on your own to finish  the proof. I have given more information than necessary.